# Should I use form1_Load event to have text box information displayed when form is opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, form-load

I have a winform with a button that the user clicks when they want to generate a certain report.  When this button is clicked, another winform opens up.  The second winform has a text box and a button to take you back to the first winform.

When the second from opens up, I want the text box to already have the report displayed.  Therefore, all the user has to do is is look at it and go back to the previous form when finished.

To do this, would I assign the text box to the appropriate method and put it in a Form1_Load event method?

I've never used the Form1_Load event method so I'm a little unsure if this is the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, in the Form_Load event you have access to all of your controls already Initialized by the form constructor via InitializeComponent().
Then you can call

```
private void Form_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "your_report_title";
}
```

Comment: @ Steve - I thought so but I wasn't sure.  I read the MSDN Library but sometimes that is like ancient Greek to me.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie if this is the only thing you need to do on this form, would be a nice change if you pass the data to be displayed in the textbox from the outside of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be the correct use of Form1_Load().

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = "Whatever is supposed to go here"
}
```

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty new, like yourself, so I try my best to answer these simple questions that I myself encountered recently.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the constructor of the form which should already be there.

```
public Form2(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Then just open the form using

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2("text that should be displayed");
form2.Show();
```